# $_SESSION изменяется при переходе на новую страницу

Tags: php, сессия

Наверное, в связи с обновлением версии РНР (а может и какой-то другой причине) при переходе на новую страницу изменяется $_SESSION

Используется прототип:

1. перед отправкой на биллинг записываем в $_SESSION некоторые параметры, уходим на биллинг
2. .... //отработка на стороне биллинга//
3. возвращаемся с биллинга на страницу успешной оплаты, забираем параметры $_SESSION

А вот теперь возникает заминка связанная с тем, что $_SESSION на странице успешной оплаты (в большинстве случаев, но не всегда) уже другой, соответственно, мы не можем забрать параметры, переданные в $_SESSION перед уходом на биллинг.

Подскажите плз, как решить, куда копать ???

Comment: А нам Вы не подскажите как решить, куда копать ? Куда смотреть ? Где код ?

Comment: Код чего?...%)  Заходим на страницу, открываем сессию session_start(); задаем параметры $_SESSION['param']=$param; $_SESSION['param2']=$param2; уходим на биллинг, возвращаемся с биллинга, открываем сессию session_start(); $_SESSION - изменился, соотв невозможно забрать из $_SESSION параметры, заданные перед уходом на биллинг. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Любая касса возвращает ответ о статусе платежа. Также любая касса поддерживает кастомные поля, в которые можно внести свою инфу..айди юзера и т.п. Вопрос - Зачем тут сессии в данном случае ? Если так принципиально - пишите в файл или базу.

Comment: Сессии нужны потому, что в данном случае, нет возможности использовать result url (а именно туда передаются значения кастомных полей), и вопрос не в том "зачем", а как исправить работу существующего прототипа?

Comment: Говоря о костылях - `Если так принципиально - пишите в файл или базу.`. Говоря про сессии - только что проверил, сессия не перезаписывается и работает нормально. Хоть четырежды я её `session_start()`. Только если destroy и последующий start, тогда очевидный результат

Comment: Ну и кстати говоря - не все кассы возвращают кастомные поля в result url. Например, киви. С другими не проверял..Вроде Яндекс тоже может фоном послать ответ без редиректа на result url.Если мы об одном говорим, конечно

Comment: Раньше и у меня проблем не было, сессии не перезаписывались, а теперь берут и перезаписываются, в этом как раз и проблема, и именно в ее решении я прошу помочь.

Comment: Что за билинг? Какой сервис используете?

Comment: Не думаю, что сервис, в данном случае, имеет какое-то значение. Очевидно ж ведь, что нужно решать эту проблему на программном уровне.... Один из проблемных - это фрикасса (тк они передают кастомные поля в только result url)

Comment: может сэкспайриться успела

Comment: Вариант с допущенной "ошибкой" в своих обработчиках не рассматриваете ? Может где то сессию в качестве теста перезаписывали и забыли..мало ли